# Set rule in Postgres for entry in Column

Tags: postgresql

I have a table called Staff I am currently creating. I have columns:

- staffNo
- fName
- lName
- position
- sex
- DOB
- salary
- branchNo

Currently, the entry I have in the postgres command line is:

```
CREATE TABLE Staff(
         staffNo     TEXT CONSTRAINT firstkey PRIMARY KEY,
         fname       TEXT NOT NULL,
         lname       TEXT NOT NULL,
         position    TEXT NOT NULL,
         sex         CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
         DOB         DATE NOT NULL,
         salary      INT NOT NULL,
         FOREIGN KEY (branchNo) REFERENCES Branch(branchNo));
```

I would like to set it so that for position, only either Manager, Assistant, or Supervisor can be inserted into that column. For sex, I would like the same to be for M or F. Can anyone provide an example of how this can be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this using the [check](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html) constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE Staff(
     staffNo     TEXT CONSTRAINT firstkey PRIMARY KEY,
     fname       TEXT NOT NULL,
     lname       TEXT NOT NULL,
     position    TEXT NOT NULL,
     sex         CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
     DOB         DATE NOT NULL,
     salary      INT NOT NULL,
     FOREIGN KEY (branchNo) REFERENCES Branch(branchNo),
     CHECK((position = 'Manager' or position = 'Assistant' or position = 'Supervisor') 
     AND (sex = 'F' OR sex = 'M')));
```

But it is more flexible if you reference those constants from other table (Perhaps a `position_table`)

Comment: Thanks so much, I am actually following these examples in a book to prepare for a job interview :)